# Retrive a Digit from a String using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

What I am trying to do is fairly simple, although I am running into difficulty. I have a string that is a url, it will have the format http://www.somedomain.com?id=someid what I want to retrive is the someid part. I figure I can use a regular expression but I'm not very good with them, this is what I tried:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(theString, @"*.?id=(/d.)");
```

I get a regex exception saying there was an error parsing the regex. The way I am reading this is `"any number of characters"` then the literal `"?id="` followed `"by any number of digits"`. I put the digits in a group so I could pull them out. I'm not sure what is wrong with this. If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I would appreciated it, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for Regex. Just use built-in utilities.

```
string query = new Uri("http://www.somedomain.com?id=someid").Query;
var dict = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);

var value = dict["id"]
```

Answer (score 4):

You've got a couple of errors in your regex. Try this:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(theString, @".*\?id=(\d+)");
```

Specifically, I:

- changed `*.` to `.*` (dot matches all non-newline chars and `*` means zero or more of the preceding)
- added a an escape sequence before the `?` because the question mark is a special charcter in regular expressions. It means zero or one of the preceding.
- changed `/d.` to `\d*` (you had the slash going the wrong way and you used dot, which was explained above, instead of `*` which was also explained above)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var match = RegEx.Match(theString, @".*\?id=(\d+)");
```

Answer (score 1):

- The error is probably due to preceding `*`. The `*` character in regex matches zero or more occurrences of previous character; so it cannot be the first character.
- Probably a typo, but shortcut for digit is `\d`, not `/d`
- `.` matches any character, you need to match one or more digits - so use a `+`
- `?` is a special character, so it needs to be escaped.

So it becomes:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(theString, @".*\?id=(\d+)");
```

That being said, regex is not the best tool for this; use a proper query string parser or things will eventually become difficult to manage.